# Cassandra Nodetool status not working: AttributeNotFoundException: No such attribute: EndpointToHostId

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, nodetool

I am getting the following Exception when I run nodetool status on my Cassandra nodes. I am using DSE 4.7, any idea what could be the issue.  All the nodes are running the same version of the DSE

```
-bash-4.1$ nodetool status
```

error: No such attribute: EndpointToHostId
-- StackTrace --

```
javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException: No such attribute: EndpointToHostId
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.getAttribute(PerInterface.java:81)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.getAttribute(MBeanSupport.java:206)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:647)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1464)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:657)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.getAttribute(RMIConnector.java:903)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:273)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.getEndpointToHostId(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeProbe.getHostIdMap(NodeProbe.java:514)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool$Status.execute(NodeTool.java:2198)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool$NodeToolCmd.run(NodeTool.java:292)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:206)
```

Comment: Is the nodetool utility which you are using is from the DSE 4.7?

Answer (score 3):

I saw this when the version of nodetool on my workstation was different that the version of Cassandra I was connecting to. Make sure you are using the same versions.